# Gnucash vs QuickBooks for both personal and business account

Tags: united-kingdom, accounting, gnucash, quickbooks

I'm considering keeping track of both personal and business accounts. I'm an old user of Gnu cash and I think I could manage with it.

What would be the benefit to swapping to a new cloud accounting software?

Comment: Do you need live access to the accounts from more than one location at a time or by more than one person at a time?

Comment: No. Not at this point

Comment: In that case, is it sufficient to keep the GnuCash data file in the cloud? "Cloud accounting" is a platform (like "PC accounting"), not a specific application. Each (cloud) application can have its pros and cons such as security, multi-user access, types of devices supported, accounting features provided, etc. The community might be able to help you better if you identify a specific cloud-based accounting application to compare GnuCash with, together with the kinds of features you're looking for in the cloud application, or limitations you're frustrated with in GnuCash, etc.

Comment: That is a great suggestion. I was mostly thinking of invoicing and keeping track of those. I guess gnucash can do that, but can it do it as well as QuickBooks or maybe mint?

Comment: GnuCash can easily be used with 'The Cloud' as well - for example, keeping Gnucash files and settings (e.g. reports) on dropbox is trivially easy.  Security is a concern with *any* cloud based approach and represents a tradeoff IMHO, albeit one that can be mitigated (e.g. cloud encryption).